# Parameters in ReduceByKey in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

While coding in Java in Spark, I have been facing the problems with parameters in reduceByKey in Spark. I didn't understand the parameters used in the reduceByKey function. I know that what reduceByKey means and the way it works. However, the codes below are a little different from the basic spark code examples (ex. word count example)

As you can see, there are two parameters in reduceByKey which are `new KrukalReducer(numPoints)` and `numSubGraphs.` `numSubGraphs` is integer value and the `KruskalReducer` is java class.

```
 mstToBeMergedResult = mstToBeMerged.mapToPair(new SetPartitionIdFunction(K)).reduceByKey(
                    new KruskalReducer(numPoints), numSubGraphs);
```

I did't understand why such integer variables are used for reduceByKey. I tried to connect two parameters to the concept with ReduceByKey but failed to get it.

I attached the java class for your information.

```
 public static final class KruskalReducer implements Function2<Iterable<Edge>, Iterable<Edge>, Iterable<Edge>>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private transient UnionFind uf = null;
        private final int numPoints;

        public KruskalReducer(int numPoints) {
            this.numPoints = numPoints;
        }

        // merge sort
        @Override
        public Iterable<Edge> call(Iterable<Edge> leftEdges, Iterable<Edge> rightEdges) throws Exception{
            uf = new UnionFind(numPoints);
            List<Edge> edges = Lists.newArrayList();
            Iterator<Edge> leftEdgesIterator = leftEdges.iterator();
            Iterator<Edge> rightEdgesIterator = rightEdges.iterator();
            Edge leftEdge = leftEdgesIterator.next();
            Edge rightEdge = rightEdgesIterator.next();
            Edge minEdge;
            boolean isLeft;
            Iterator<Edge> minEdgeIterator;
            final int numEdges = numPoints - 1;
            do {
                if (leftEdge.getWeight() < rightEdge.getWeight()) {
                    minEdgeIterator = leftEdgesIterator;
                    minEdge = leftEdge;
                    isLeft = true;
                } else {
                    minEdgeIterator = rightEdgesIterator;
                    minEdge = rightEdge;
                    isLeft = false;
                }
                if (uf.unify(minEdge.getLeft(), minEdge.getRight())) {
                    edges.add(minEdge);
                }
                minEdge = minEdgeIterator.hasNext() ? minEdgeIterator.next() : null;
                if (isLeft) {
                    leftEdge = minEdge;
                } else {
                    rightEdge = minEdge;
                }
            }while (minEdge != null && edges.size() < numEdges);
            minEdge = isLeft ? rightEdge : leftEdge;
            minEdgeIterator = isLeft ? rightEdgesIterator : leftEdgesIterator;

            while (edges.size() < numEdges && minEdgeIterator.hasNext()) {
                if (uf.unify(minEdge.getLeft(), minEdge.getRight())) {
                    edges.add(minEdge);
                }
                minEdge = minEdgeIterator.next();
            }
            return edges;
        }
    }
```

Additionally, the full related codes are shown as below. (You can skip this code if you get confused)

```
   JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Edge>> mstToBeMerged = partitions.combineByKey(new CreateCombiner(),
                    new Merger(), new KruskalReducer(numPoints));


JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Edge>> mstToBeMergedResult = null;
while (numSubGraphs > 1){
     numSubGraphs = (numSubGraphs + (K - 1)) / K;
     mstToBeMergedResult = mstToBeMerged.mapToPair(new SetPartitionIdFunction(K)).reduceByKey(
              new KruskalReducer(numPoints), numSubGraphs);
     mstToBeMerged = mstToBeMergedResult;
     displayResults(mstToBeMerged);
}


private static class CreateCombiner implements Function<Edge, Iterable<Edge>>{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Iterable<Edge> call(Edge edge) throws Exception {
            List<Edge> edgeList = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(1);
            edgeList.add(edge);
            return edgeList;
        }
    }

    private static class Merger implements Function2<Iterable<Edge>, Edge, Iterable<Edge>>{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Iterable<Edge> call(Iterable<Edge> list, Edge edge) throws Exception {
            List<Edge> mergeList = Lists.newArrayList(list);
            mergeList.add(edge);
            return mergeList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did't understand why such integer variables are used for
>   reduceByKey. I tried to connect two parameters to the concept with
>   ReduceByKey but failed to get it.

If I'm reading the right overload:

```
def reduceByKey(func: JFunction2[V, V, V], numPartitions: Int): JavaPairRDD[K, V] =
  fromRDD(rdd.reduceByKey(func, numPartitions))
```

Then the number you're passing is the number of partitions in the underlying RDD. Because `reduceByKey` is a shuffle boundary operation, data will get re-partitioned and passing that numbers allows you to control how many partitions will be allocated.